# iOS AutoLayout LayoutGuide disappears on Memory Warning

Tags: ios, layout, autolayout, didreceivememorywarning, memory-warning

I'm having some issues with the _UILayoutGuide that dictates the top and bottom of the screen in my app home screen. Everything works fine until a Memory Warning is triggered in a ViewController that's further in the navigation stack and I try to go back to home. For some reason the top and bottom _UILayoutGuide disappear and the constraints that where attached to them just break, making the view either go up or down.

Is there some way to prevent this? alternatives? Where can I hook the view if there's no other option?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the ViewController's view itself going down? Or the subview of ViewController's view is affected?

Comment: The view controller itself stays just fine. The problem is that a view inside the main view in the controller is going up because it looses the constraint that hooks it up to the layout guide at the bottom or the layout guide itself is gone.